# In multiple definite integrals, if the region is the same in all of them, does the order of the differentials matter?

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral

> In multiple definite integrals, if the region is the same, does the order of the differentials matter?

I think the question is clear, but as an example in 2 dimensions, is it true that

$$\int_X\int_X f(x,y)dx\ dy=\int_X\int_X f(x,y)dy\ dx$$

for all valid regions $X$?

Comment: $f$ needs to satisfy certain conditions: if it is positive, [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) applies and you can change the order without issue. If it is unbounded both above and below, you need $\lvert f \rvert$ to have finite integral (see [Fubini–Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#The_Fubini–Tonelli_theorem) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb R$ be defined by 
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(x,y)\ne(0,0)}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^1 -\left(\frac1{1+y^2}\right)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= -\frac\pi4
\end{align}
while
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(\frac1{1+x^2}\right)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac\pi4.
\end{align}
$$